# Nested traversal gremlin query for Titan db

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am wondering how is possible to have a gremlin query which returns results in a nested format. Suppose there is property graph as follows:

`USER` and `PAGE` vertices with some properties such as `AGE` for `USER` vertex;

`FOLLOW` edge between `USER` and `PAGE`;

I am looking for a single efficient query which gives all Users with age greater than 20 years and all of the followed pages by those users. I can do that using a simple loop from the application side and per each iteration use a simple traversal query. Unfortunately, such solution is not efficient for me, since it will generate lots of queries and network latency could be huge in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what your definition of "efficient" is, but keep in mind that this is a typical OLAP use-case and you shouldn't expect fast OLTP realtime responses.

That said, the query should be as simple as:

```
g.V().has("USER", "AGE", gt(20)).as("user").
  map(out("FOLLOW").fold()).as("pages").
  select("user", "pages")
```

A small example using the modern sample graph:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal().withComputer()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], graphcomputer]
gremlin> g.V().has("person", "age", gt(30)).as("user").
           map(out("created").fold()).as("projects").
           select("user","projects")
==>[user:v[6], projects:[v[3]]]
==>[user:v[4], projects:[v[5], v[3]]]
```

Comment: what a perfect answer!
but problem is that when a user follows many users all of that users will load on memory

Comment: @pinokio probably using limit() could be a solution in this situation.

Comment: @Daniel Kuppitz How can I get certain data (e.g. username, surname etc.) of user/projects?

Comment: You would choose a different result structure: `g.V().has("person", "age", gt(30)).as("u").valueMap("name","age").as("user").select("u").out("created").valueMap("name","lang").group().by(select("user"))`

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy:

```
g.V().label('user').has('age',gt(20))
.match(__.as('user').out('follows').as('page'))
.select('user','page')
```

just attention when you are using this query in gremlin, gremlin gives you null pointer exception you can use it in code and check if 'page' exist get that.